# Как компилировать MASM на MacOS?

Tags: masm32, nasm, masm

Есть такая проблема. У меня MacOS (Monterey 12.1) и я хочу скомпилировать MASM код. Я знаю, что это компилятор Microsoft и с Apple он возможно дружить не будет, но тем не менее.

Например, NASM мне удалось скомпилировать, а вот MASM уже нет. Может кто занимался подобным и знает как это сделать?

Comment: Преположим вы сумели запустить MASM и получить объектный модуль. Как вы собираетесь его использовать?

Comment: Я решил эту проблему установкой DOSBox. Теперь я могу компилировать и запускать программы там.